# find-new/posts&recent=1 as homepage: what about SEO?

Tags: seo, htaccess, url, pagerank

I can't change the URL of my website with .htaccess, because the query does not work anymore if I make it a pretty URL, so I am desparate to know what impact this will have on SEO. I mean, I have to use this one, because my community wants to see this page as the homepage, which I can understand, but I don't know what effect this will have on my pageranking.

The funny part is that this page has no canonical URL and it has `noindex` on it, so that is not good at all, but I am asking you for the URL in the address bar specifically. Can someone explain to me what will happen?

Comment: May be you should think about the use of that URL, I can't think of any valid reason to have that. I'm no expert on mod_rewrite, but I'm sure that you find help to make your system work with an easier to type/remember URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best address, but good positioning has many elements involved and the URL is just one of them, as usual, if you have good content, no errors on the code, no missing pages, fast loading times, etc., there should be no problem.

The search engines record the URL as one resource and that's it. I'm sorry if this feels too short, but there is not much more to add. A resource should have a valid URL, yours is, so it will be recorded on their database with that one and accessed whenever requested.

It's not good for users to write directly, but I assume that their can type just site.com and some internals will direct them to that URL. If that's not the case and the user is required to write that exact URL, then you have a big problem since the only reasonable way to access your site is though search results, following a link.

Comment: Well, it is my homepage, so they are being redirected to this page, that is not the problem. My problem is that the URL is very ugly... but anyhow, I guess I have to live with it. Thanks.